# How to lose focus from a field programmatically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with some input fields and one submit button. When I hit enter the submit handler triggers. When it's almost finished I clear the form this way:

```
this.changeForm.$setUntouched();
this.changeForm.$setPristine();
```

I cleared the form, but the last field I was in is **still focused**. How to clear the form to a brand new state? Or how to lose focus from form fields?

Comment: blur is the opposite of focus

Comment: Yup. [`HTMLElement.blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur)

Comment: If you're going to remove focus from a field I think it best to explicitly move it to whichever control the user would likely need next. (So if you're clearing the form to allow further items to be added put focus in the first field.)

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tried it yet,but can you try this

```
//"focusedInputField" property of changeForm is the currently focused field
this.changeForm.focusedInputField.blur();

this.changeForm.$setUntouched();
this.changeForm.$setPristine();
```